# Save model instance doesn't work in Yii

Tags: php, yii

I have these codes but save() method doesn't work. What is the problem?

```
public function rules()
{
    return array(
        array('name', 'required'),
                    array('name site_id', 'unique'),
                    array('status, site_id', 'numerical', 'integerOnly'=>true),
        array('name, author', 'length', 'max'=>50),
        array('version', 'length', 'max'=>10),
                    array('config_content', 'safe'),
        array('id, name, author, version, status, config_content, site_id', 'safe', 'on'=>'search'),
    );
}
```

and

```
$new_row = new Module;
$new_row->name = 'test';
$new_row->config_content = 'asasfdfd';
$new_row->site_id = 2;
$new_row->status = 0;

if($new_row->save())
   echo 'Yes!';
else
   echo 'No!';
```

Comment: At else section dump $new_row->getErrors() and check it by yourself

Comment: the error is : Array ( [name] => Array ( [0] => Name "test" has already been taken. ) [site_id] => Array ( [0] => Site Id "1" has already been taken. ) ) but I've defined combination of name and and site_id to be unique in rules().

Comment: Unique validator does not work with several attributes in Yii ver < 2. You may use http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/unique-attributes-validator/ for this

Comment: big thanks Andrey. That solved my problem. I am sorry for what is going on in your country with wishes of peace.

Answer (score 3):

Hi from what I can see the most likely cause will be because there is a "," missing in the following rule

```
array('name site_id', 'unique'),
```

should be

```
array('name, site_id', 'unique'),
```